# How to create a nested dictionary from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings: `tree_list = ['Parents', 'Children', 'GrandChildren']`

How can i take that list and convert it to a nested dictionary like this?

```
tree_dict = {
    'Parents': {
        'Children': {
            'GrandChildren' : {}
        }
    }
}

print tree_dict['Parents']['Children']['GrandChildren']
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This easiest way is to build the dictionary starting from the inside out:

```
tree_dict = {}
for key in reversed(tree_list):
    tree_dict = {key: tree_dict}
```

With an arbitrary terminal value:

```
result = ... # terminal value 
for k in reversed(keys):
    result = {k:  result}
# result is the nested dict
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that if the leave has to be some other value than a `dict`, one can just initialise `tree_dict` accordingly. For example, `tree_dict = 42` leads to a nested dict where the innermost value is `42`.

Answer (score 13):

Using a recursive function:

```
tree_list = ['Parents', 'Children', 'GrandChildren']

def build_tree(tree_list):
    if tree_list:
        return {tree_list[0]: build_tree(tree_list[1:])}
    return {}

build_tree(tree_list)
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a short solution:

```
lambda l:reduce(lambda x,y:{y:x},l[::-1],{})
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands ah I totally agree with you. But readability is just one criterion.

Comment: You can save two characters by passing `{}` as the third argument to `reduce()` instead of prepending it to the list.

Comment: @Sven Marnach Good one!