# Write to dictionary using list-path

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to write to a dictionary with a 'list-path'. I have:

```py
container = {}
path = ['foo', 'bar']
data = [1, 2, 3]
```

And would like to get

```py
container = {
    'foo' : {
        'bar' : [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

To read, I am very enthusiastic about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033676/2646505), which says that **to read**:

```py
data = functools.reduce(operator.getitem, path, container)
```

But now I'm not managing to get the opposite right...

(I guess one could use recursion, but a one-line solution seems near!)

Comment: @jdaz Thanks! Maybe I'm naive, but those answer tell me how to build the nested dictionary (to build `container`) but not yet how to write `data` to it. Also... A one-liner would be nice!

Comment: Problem with reduce is that it only works for functions that accept two parameters, `operator.setitem` requires 3 parameters (container, index, value). I'll scratch my head a bit more...

Comment: Tom, you can change the one-liner answer in that question to just use `data` as the initial object for `reduce`: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, path[::-1], data)`

Comment: Amazing @jdaz !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a one liner, but I changed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401961/7363404) a bit so it would add the data to the last element.

```
path = ['foo','bar']
data = [1,2,3]
container = {}
for key in reversed(path):
    if (key == path[-1]):
        container = {key: data}
    else:
        container = {key: container}
```

This is the output: `{'foo': {'bar': [1, 2, 3]}}`

Edit: Nevermind, I found a one liner based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402031/7363404)

```
import functools
path = ['foo','bar']
data = [1,2,3]
container = functools.reduce(lambda x,y:{y:x},path[:-1],{path[-1]: data})
```

Comment: To make it fit the question it could be considered to add `container = functools.reduce(...`

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'll add it right now

Comment: Nice improvement!