# Python 3: Creating a nested dict dynamically from a list

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have an array `['a', 'b', 'c']` , and I want to create a nested object like below.

```
{ a: {
       b : {
          c: {}
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and how it went wrong

Comment: This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401886/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a nested dictionary from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401886/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: That's not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?
I implement it as Dictionary

```py
base = ["a", "b", "c"]

result = {}
for b in base[::-1]:
    result = {b: result}

print(result)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```