# nested dictionary from lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have three lists (of lists) - `index_1`, `index_2` and `index_3`. I want to combine them to make a nested dictionary. The keys of the top level of the dictionary should be `index_1 = ['item1','item2','item3']`. The second level should be keyed by `index_2` (which has 3 elements corresponding to `'item1'`, `'item2'`, and `'item3'`). The values in the second level of the dictionary should contain values and be stored in a list as in `index_3`.

I am a bit stuck and think I am creating overly complicated loops shown below. Any comments would be great.

```
# input lists
index_1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
index_2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
index_3 = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [99, 100], [0, 1, 2]]

# desired output
my_dict = {'item1' : {'a' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'b' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'c' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
           'item2' : {'d' : [99, 100], 'e' : [99, 100], 'f' : [99, 100]},
           'item3' : {'g' : [0, 1, 2], 'h' : [0, 1, 2], 'i' : [0, 1, 2]}}

# my loop that didnt work
d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
for i in range(len(index_1)):
    for x, y, z in zip([index_1[i]], [index_2[i]], [index_3[i]]):
        d[x][y] = [z]
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401886/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: hi @jspcal thanks yeah I did see that but the structure is different thats using a single list rather than multiple, with varying numbers of fields. I have been trying with zips e.g. `from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict()

for i in range(len(index_1)):
    for x, y, z in zip([index_1[i]], index_2[i], index_3[i]):
        dic[x][y]= [z]
` but no joy

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the loops, and how they didn't work. Also, please see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can step along multiple lists in lockstep with `zip`, e.g.,

```
zip(index_1, index_2, index_3)
```

At each step, the first element is the key, and the next ones make the nested dictionary. The nested dictionary can be made by `dict.fromkeys` as long as you're ok with having the same reference in all the values:

```
d = {}
for k, nk, nv in zip(index_1, index_2, index_3):
    d[k] = dict.fromkeys(nk, nv)
```

Otherwise, you need to make a new list for each element:

```
d = {}
for k, nk, nv in zip(index_1, index_2, index_3):
    d[k] = {kk: list(nv) for kk in nk}
```

`list(nv)`, `nv[:]` and `nv.copy()` are all idiomatic, and a great case of "exceptions prove the rule" for python's ideal of having one right way to do things.

You can now simplify the whole thing into a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: {kk: list(nv) for kk in nk} for k, nk, nv in zip(index_1, index_2, index_3)}
```

Comment: This is a really great explanation thanks so much!

Comment: @nac. Glad it helps. We were all beginners once

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `defaultdict` or that extra loop, you can just `zip` them together like below:

```py
index_1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
index_2 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
index_3 = [[0,1,2,3,4],[99,100], [0,1,2]]

dic = {}
for x, y, z in zip(index_1, index_2, index_3):
    dic[x] = {}
    for k in y:
        dic[x][k] = z[:]
```

The `z[:]` is to ensure a new list is created and the same reference isn't reused for all keys.

---

This code will still work if you want to use `dic = defaultdict(defaultdict)`, the benefit being you can omit `dic[x] = {}` from your loop. It may make more sense to go with `defaultdict(dict)` there though, since there's no benefit to the nested ones being a defaultdict.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
index_1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
index_2 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
index_3 = [[0,1,2,3,4],[99,100], [0,1,2]]

vals=zip(index_2, index_3)
di={}
for k1 in index_1:
    ct=next(vals)
    di[k1]={k:ct[1] for k in ct[0]}
```

If you want the individual lists inside to be copies, do:

```
di[k1]={k:list(ct[1]) for k in ct[0]}
```

Either case:

```
>>> di
{'item1': {'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}, 'item2': {'d': [99, 100], 'e': [99, 100], 'f': [99, 100]}, 'item3': {'g': [0, 1, 2], 'h': [0, 1, 2], 'i': [0, 1, 2]}}
```

Given your example output:

```
>>> di==my_dict
True
```