# Python - Add nested dictionary items from a list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find a quick and easy way to add nested items to an existing Python dictionary. This is my most recent dictionary:

```py
myDict = {
  "a1": {
    "a2": "Hello"
  }
}
```

I want to use a function similar to this one to add new nested values:

```py
myDict = add_nested(myDict, ["b1", "b2", "b3"], "z2")
myDict = add_nested(myDict, ["c1"], "z3")
```

After running the function, I expect my dictionary to look like this:

```
myDict = {
  "a1": {
    "a2": "z1"
  },
  "b1": {
    "b2": {
      "b3": "z2"
    }
  },
  "c1": "z3"
}
```

How can I create a Pythonic function (`add_nested`) that achieves this?

Comment: Did you look at: [How to create a nested dictionary from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401886/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401961/3494774), call it `make_nested` and then `myDict.update(make_nested(keys, value))`